# Magento 2 Shipping Price

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods

We have found the issue in default magento2.1.7, Flat price is not showing up in while placing the order.

Please find the screenshots:

**Admin:**
[image]

**Frontend:**
[image]

Thanks

Comment: It's working fine in Magento 2.1.7. Please check after disable third party modules.

Comment: Yes, We have disabled the module and tried its getting same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete the current product in cart and customer logout once. Do flush cache and check the result.

This will fix your issue.

Comment: please let me know your result to me

Comment: ok we will try and get back you

Comment: ok.......................